# Blocking Android TouchDown access to Exchange

Tags: exchange-2003, android

I found out recently that a user with an Android phone is using TouchDown to sync with his Exchange 2003 account.  What's the best way of blocking this?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to if you can and are willing to share that (Not sure how to block myself) ?

Comment: Corporate policy prohibits people from syncing mail to their personal devices.  The exception is BlackBerry's on the BES and ActiveSync devices, as we can enforce password polices and remotely wipe if needed.  I thought this kind of policy was pretty standard in the corporate world.

Comment: Touchdown allegedly supports ActiveSync and remote wipe: http://www.nitrodesk.com/dk_touchdownFeatures.aspx.  I say allegedly because I haven't worked with it before....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touchdown accesses the Exchange Server via ActiveSync or Outlook Web Access.  You can disable those two, but chances are many of your users use the OWA (Blackberry phones not on BES use OWA also).

I don't know of a way to keep those two open AND block Touchdown.

Comment: I can only comment on my own answer, but in regards to password policies & remote wipe, Touchdown can be setup to do both of those things.  Just a suggestion if you want to work with the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Outlook Mobile Access from the Exchange server.  http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/OMA_Exchange_Server_2003.html.  You can do this globally or just for the specific user (Properties -> Exchange Features tab).

Edit:  as Joeqwerty pointed out, you need to disable UIS http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997489(EXCHG.65).aspx

Comment: OMA doesn't control ActiveSync. You need to disable UIN and UDN on the user account in order to disable ActiveSync.

Comment: @Joeqwerty : You're right.  I've updated my answer